# What are the weak points of Abbadon Crusher mutants in Rage 2?

Tags: rage-2

What are the weak points of the Abadon mutants scattered around the world of Rage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abbadon Crusher mutants are all unique bosses with different weak spots.

This list is sourced from [GamesHedge](https://www.gameshedge.com/rage-2-abadon-crusher-mutants/)

- Lug the Nut’s weak point is the head
- Smeggle The Vile’s weak point is the chest
- Sackhead’s weak point is the back
- Digg and Dugg don’t have a weak point - but the arena is easily accessible by vehicle making for a fair fight
- Grull the Juggernaut’s weak point is the unarmored legs

Generic abbadon mutants can spawn in a crater south of Gunbarrel too. These don’t seem to have a weak point but can again be fought by vehicle